# C++ given a list of strings, how to get respective variable addresses from a class

Tags: c++

I have a class

```
class MyClass{
public:
   int var_x;
   int var_y;
   int var_z;
}
```

Then a file.txt:

```
var_y
var_z
```

In the main I want to be able to get the address of each variable in file.txt:

```
int main()
{
     MyClass *obj;
     obj = new MyClass();
     std::vector<std::string>> varList = readFile("file.txt");

     // I need generic code that would do the following:
     // But the class can have any number (or named) variables
     // And the text file can have any subset of the variables
     std::cout << "var_y  " << &(obj->var_y) << std::endl;
     std::cout << "var_y  " << &(obj->var_z) << std::endl;

     delete obj;
     return 0;

     // Pseudo code would be
     for var in varList:
         addr = get_addr_from_string(var)
}
```

Comment: C++ does not support reflection. If you want something like relfection, you will have to keep track of the variables in the class when you declare them.

Comment: C++ does not have Reflection (yet) so you need to do that manually through code.

Comment: how is `obj` related to that file ?

Comment: C++ doesn't allow a variable number of members. Just put the vector into `MyClass` so you can do `obj.var[index];`.

Comment: Ok, I didn't think it was supported but I wasn't sure. Thank you for your feedback. This is interesting http://jackieokay.com/2017/04/13/reflection1.html

Comment: Interesting how your pseudo code is in python.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah That is to be expected. Python is just executable pseudo code.

Comment: Sorry, updated the source code. My apologies nwp. And I usually go straight to python when I am prototyping something out. Sometimes transitioning into C++ isn't so trivial. Hence this question :)

Comment: It doesn't matter for this question, but generally stay away from `new`. It just makes everything difficult.

Comment: The return type of main should definitely not be void.

Comment: @eflanigan00 -- *Sometimes transitioning into C++ isn't so trivial.* -- Please do not use Python as a guide in writing C++ programs, or any other language as a guide in writing C++ programs.  Learn C++ as if no other language exists.

Comment: I like your advice PaulMcKenzie.

Comment: Why so many down votes? I may not have phrased the question very well but there is no trivial solution to the problem.

Comment: In cases, where you read identifiers from a file at runtime, `std::unordered_map` is generally the go-to choice. So instead of individual member variables in `MyClass`, you should just have a map. You may also want to add desired members to the map with default values in `MyClass` constructor, and possibly make the map private and provide getter and setter methods so that users can't add new keys (if that is how you want it).

Answer (score 2):

```
using Gettor = std::function< std::any(void*) > get_ptr;

template<class T>
struct ReflectedClass {
  static std::unordered_map<std::string, Gettor> members;
  template<class U>
  static U* get( T* t, const char* name ) {
    auto it = members.find(name);
    if (it == members.end()) return nullptr;
    std::any a = it->second( t );
    U** ptr = std::any_cast<U*>(&a);
    if (!ptr) return nullptr;
    return *ptr;
  }
};

#define TO_STR2(X) ##X
#define TO_STR(X) TO_STR2(X)
#define REFLECTED_MEMBER( CLASS, NAME ) \
  ReflectedClass<CLASS>::members[ TO_STR(NAME) ] = \
  []( void* ptr )->std::any { \
    return std::addressof( (CLASS*)(ptr)->NAME ); \
  }
```

Then simply do

```
REFLECTED_MEMBER(MyClass, var_x )
REFLECTED_MEMBER(MyClass, var_y )
REFLECTED_MEMBER(MyClass, var_z )
```

and you can call

```
MyClass foo;
int* ptr = ReflectedClass<MyClass>::get<int>( &foo, "var_x" );
```

and it returns a pointer to `foo.var_x`.

This is a bad idea, don't do it.

Comment: Thanks Yakk, can you elaborate why this is a bad idea? I'm planning on having the assumption that all classes with these properties are dynamic memory.

Comment: @eflanigan00 Because it is a way you'd do it in a scripting language with dynamically typed data and reflectable structures.  This isn't a scripting language.  The data isn't dynamically typed, the reflection is manual, and it is a lot like wanting to fly so you weld wings onto a horse.